# HTML Default Option in Select Using PHP Is Not Working

Tags: php, html, html-select, selected

I'm bug-proofing a form that allows data editing for book entries in a database. Everything is working except for the drop-down box. The drop-down box automatically populates itself with every unique entry in a specific field in the database table, and that part works perfectly. However, when people click to edit a book all the fields are populated with that books information, and I wanted the drop-down box to default to the correct value for that book. My solution was to check each value as it populates the drop-down box against the actual book's value for that field and if they match, make it the "selected" value.

It is not working. The box is still populating fine, but it is not defaulting. Here is the code for the drop-down box.

```
<span style="margin-left:10px;">
 Publication Type: 
 <select name="publicationType" >
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="">-------------------------</option>
  <?php 
   $lPub = '';
   if(array_key_exists('publicationType',$_REQUEST)) $lPub = $_REQUEST['publicationType'];
    $lPubArr = $datasetManager->getPublicationType();
    foreach($lPubArr as $pubStr){
    if($pubStr == $bookArr['publicationType']){
     echo '<option '.($lPub==$pubStr?'selected="selected"':'').'>'.$pubStr.'</option>'."\n";
    }
    else{
     echo '<option '.($lPub==$pubStr?'':'').'>'.$pubStr.'</option>'."\n";
    }
   } 
  ?>
 </select>
</span>
```

I can provide what all the variables are if needed. I don't see what I'm doing wrong, but maybe someone will be able to catch an obvious mistake.

Thank you,
Kai

Comment: just curious ... you have this `($lPub==$pubStr?'':'')` so in either scenario you populate nothing? why do you have this there at all?

Comment: did you look at the page source to see if the `selected` attribute even shows up?

Comment: perhaps you can log the value of `$pubStr` and `$bookArr['publicationType']`

Comment: You know, when I looked at the source the selected attribute did not show up. Does this mean it's defaulting to false in the `($lPub==$pubStr?'selected="selected"':'')` statement?

Comment: yeah it looks like the `$lPub` value is not what you expect, please provide a var dump for each variable in your iterations

Comment: and what is the `$bookArr` is for ?

Comment: I just realized my `($pubStr == $bookArr['publicationType'])` is a redundancy.. The original code was supposed to set the default, and it was not working. Thanks for the replies. I'll investigate why `$lPub` is not drawing the correct value.

Comment: This was redundant:
`if($pubStr == $bookArr['publicationType']){ echo ''.$pubStr.''."\n"; } else{ echo ''.$pubStr.''."\n"; }`

The first if statement in that code worked, but the secondary and tertiary if statements were causing the problem. $lPub was not pulling the correct, or any data.

To fix the problem I changed this:
`if(array_key_exists('publicationType',$_REQUEST)) $lPub = $_REQUEST['publicationType'];`

to this:
`if($bookArr['publicationType']) $lPub = $bookArr['publicationType'];`

This was a very local problem, but thought I would give a proper answer.

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this will help but try this:

```
<?php 
   $lPub = '';
   if( array_key_exists('publicationType',$_REQUEST) )
        $lPub = $_REQUEST['publicationType'];
   $lPubArr = $datasetManager->getPublicationType();
   foreach($lPubArr as $pubStr){
     echo '<option '.($lPub==$pubStr?'selected="selected"':'').'>'.$pubStr.'</option>'."\n";
   }
```

---

I removed this condition:

```
f($pubStr == $bookArr['publicationType'])
```

since I didn't get what the `$bookArr['publicationType']` is used for, perhaps you left it there by mistake

Comment: That is actually what I originally had, and the new if statement was a redundancy which I accidentally added. I'm trying to figure out why the original was not working now.